# Remove recursion from this datalog program

Tags: recursion, datalog

I have a datalog program:

```
S(X,Y) <-- P(X,Y)
S(X,Y) <-- P(X,Z), S(Z,W)
```

How can I remove recursion from my program, expressing S in a non-recursive way?

This will allow me to translate the S definition into relational algebra (SQL).

Comment: Are you sure you're stating the problem correctly? The second rule for `S(X,Y)` doesn't mention `Y` on rhs. Then this isn't recursion/you aren't grounding `W`.

Comment: Hint: What does a Horn clause with no commas state/mean? How does extending with one comma change what a Horn clause states/means? How does adding a rule change what a program states/means? PS What have you been told & seen in examples about ansswering such a question? What is your textbook/reference name & edition? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) PS SQL <> relational algebra. Which one? Anyway: You say your larger task involves one of those; but right now your question doesn't. (Should it?)